# iPhone/iMessage question

Tags: iphone

If I lost my iPhone and suspended the number but iMessage from my laptop, do the iMessages I send from the laptop continue to be sent to my phone?

The people I iMessage are getting the messages as my number--which I suspended. I'm confused because I don't want someone to find my iPhone and have all of my messages and information along with my apple ID.

I have not tried to contact Apple yet but that will be my next step.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage is connected with your iCloud E-Mail-Address as well. So if somebody unlocks your iPhone, this person will see all of your messages.

[This Apple Support document](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ts5185) describes the ways necessary to stop iMessage on your lost phone:

> **If you didn't turn off or deactivate iMessage before switching to a
>   non-Apple phone, other iOS devices will still try to use iMessage** to
>   send text messages to your phone number.
>
> If you still have your iPhone, follow these steps to turn off iMessage
>   and deregister your phone number:
>
> 1. If you transferred your SIM card from the iPhone to a non-Apple
>      phone, put it back in the iPhone.
> 2. Make sure that you're connected to the cellular data network.
> 3. Tap Settings > Messages and turn iMessage off.
>
> If you don't have access to your iPhone, or if you can't deactivate
>   iMessage from your iPhone, [please contact Apple Support](http://www.apple.com/support/contact/). Support for
>   this issue is free.